# Old i/0 scheduler in ubuntu 12.4.2

Tags: 12.04

i am using ubuntu 12.04.2 and 12.04.1

on ubuntu 12.04.1 its

```
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
```

and on ubuntu 12.04.2 its

```
io scheduler deadline registered (default)
```

Why is ubuntu's latest LTS downgraded to deadline

Comment: What kernel versions are you running? 12.04.2 includes the Quantal kernel (3.5) by default on new installation, while the 12.04.{0,1} had the 3.2 kernel. And did you test this on a full installation or from live media? The live media might be optimized for optical media (just guessing).

Comment: its showing 3.2.0-45-virtual

Comment: both are virtual machines on 12.4.2 kernel is  3.2.0-45-virtual
and on 12.4.1 with 3.2.0-33-generic

Comment: You've installed a different kernel flavour. `-virtual` and `-generic` are not comparable. I guess that deadline is considered faster on virtual machines as the host operating system has to schedule the I/O again anyway.

Comment: that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307734/old-i-0-scheduler-in-ubuntu-12-4-2?noredirect=1#comment387680_307734), you're running two different kernel flavours on the machines:

`3.2.0-33-generic` for 12.04.1 and 
 `3.2.0-45-virtual` for 12.04.2

`generic` is for general purpose hardware and the `virtual` is optimised for virtual machines. Specifically on the disk I/O part, I can imagine that a scheduler is of much less relevance as it won't be accessing raw disks, but virtual disks instead. The host operating system will have to reschedule it anyway when it writes to the physical disk.

Bottom line: you can't compare those two kernels.